# Get bid simulator results via Google ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I've been trying to get the results from the bid simulator in Google ads via the API but have not been successful. I have tried to follow the steps outlined by google in these guides:

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9634060?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/bid-landscapes#python_3

I have very slightly modified the code and it does run:

```
from googleads import adwords

CAMPAIGN_ID = '---------'
PAGE_SIZE = 100


def main(client, campaign_id):
    # Initialize appropriate service.
    data_service = client.GetService('DataService', version='v201809')

    # Get all the campaigns for this account.
    selector = {
        'fields': ['CampaignId', 'CriterionId', 'StartDate', 'EndDate',
                   'BidModifier', 'LocalClicks', 'LocalCost', 'LocalImpressions',
                   'TotalLocalClicks', 'TotalLocalCost', 'TotalLocalImpressions',
                   'RequiredBudget'],
        'paging': {
            'startIndex': 0,
            'numberResults': PAGE_SIZE
        },
        'predicates': [{
            'field': 'CampaignId', 'operator': 'IN', 'values': [campaign_id]
        }]
    }

    # Set initial values.
    offset = 0
    more_pages = True

    while more_pages is True:
        num_landscape_points = 0
        page = data_service.getCampaignCriterionBidLandscape(selector)

        # Display results.
        if 'entries' in page:
            for bid_modifier_landscape in page['entries']:
                num_landscape_points = 0
            print(f'Found campaign-level criterion bid modifier landscapes for '
                  f"criterion with ID {bid_modifier_landscape['criterionId']},"
                  f" start date {bid_modifier_landscape['startDate']}, end date     {bid_modifier_landscape['endDate']},"
                  f" and landscape points:")
            for landscape_point in bid_modifier_landscape['landscapePoints']:
                num_landscape_points += 1
                print(f"\tbid modifier: {landscape_point['bidModifier']},"
                      f" clicks: {landscape_point['clicks']},"
                      f" cost: {landscape_point['cost']['microAmount']},"
                      f" impressions: {landscape_point['impressions']},"
                      f"total clicks: {landscape_point['totalLocalClicks']},"
                      f" total cost: {landscape_point['totalLocalCost']['microAmount']},"
                      f" total impressions: {landscape_point['totalLocalImpressions']},"
                      f"and required budget: {landscape_point['requiredBudget']['microAmount']}")
        else:
            print('No bid modifier landscapes found.')

        # Need to increment by the total # of landscape points within the page,
        # NOT the number of entries (bid landscapes) in the page.
        offset += num_landscape_points
        selector['paging']['startIndex'] = str(offset)
        more_pages = num_landscape_points >= PAGE_SIZE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize client object.
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

    main(adwords_client, CAMPAIGN_ID)
```

This does not however let me get the predicted conversion value, only the clicks and impressions etc which is not really what I am looking for. This seems to line up with the documentation but in the GUI I can get conversion value but seemingly no matter what key I try to query for the API won't let me get the same simulator output as in the GUI.

Any thoughts?